# Перестала работать конструкция

Tags: wordpress

Переносил сайт со старой версии Wordpress, перестала работать конструкция вида:

```
<?php ( get_the_term_list(get_the_ID, 'taxonomy_authors','',', ') )? printf( __( '<p class="hentry-tags">%1$s</p>', 'unspoken' ),  get_the_term_list(get_the_ID, 'taxonomy_authors','',', ') ) : ''; ?>
```

Раньше выводила список тегов из кастомной таксономии. Сейчас не выводит ничего.
В тоже время конструкция:

```
<?php echo get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'taxonomy_authors', "" ) ?>
```

работает.

В чем может быть дело?

Comment: а в первом варианте у вас так и есть `get_the_term_list(get_the_ID,...` (т.е. константа `get_the_ID` вместо функции `get_the_ID()`)? Или это при создании вопроса так получилось?

Comment: Первый вариант был полностью рабочий. Но на данный момент он ничего не выводит. Втрой приммер взял из кодекса для проверки работоспособностит. Он сейчас работает. Вопрос в том, почему первый вариант не работает сейчас.

Answer (score 0):

Кажется вы пропустили `get_the_ID()` вызове функции, и она вам всегда возвращает FALSE, так как не может найти пост, а в конструкции в том случае выводит '' - пусто. Должно быть:

```
 <?php ( get_the_term_list(get_the_ID(), 'taxonomy_authors','',', ') )? printf( __( '<p class="hentry-tags">%1$s</p>', 'unspoken' ),  get_the_term_list(get_the_ID, 'taxonomy_authors','',', ') ) : ''; ?>
```